# Action Automation with Server Side Clock Timestamp JS PHP

Tags: javascript, php, time, server, clock

I need to get a time server-clock in JS or PHP, i think JS it's better for server-side.

Aniway i have a PHP page that includes all rows in the table "rows" of the database.
Table "rows" have three columns: ID(consecutive), DATE(m-d-Y), TIME(H:i).

The script i need have to check the current server time, if between the last rows published and the current time are minimum 10 minutes, it creates another row in the database with current date and current timestamp.

Obviously i thought about the JS's getDate(); function but maybe with both JS and PHP the user needs to open the page in order to start the clock, i need that the server counts it even with no visits.
Another way should be making the client script and start a process that execute locally on the machine the script that check if the timestamp is higher every X mins but it's not a clean work.

Thanks to all guys! :)

Comment: Javascript date objects will return client side dates, so if you want to use javascript then look into getting back the time stamps from an http request or just use php

Comment: Yep i'm actually trying to figure this out with PHP, but even if i can get the current server timestamp, i can obviously get it when a visitor execute the script visiting my website. So i want a server-side script that even check if the last row is published no more of 10 mins ago, in order to have a page with a published row every 10 mins.

Comment: Just echo back the date, as a matter of a fact you can echo back the date to a javascript date object and that will be a server side date I believe, and you can check the speck on that for logging in from different time zones if that will be one of your issues

Comment: if the posts are in a sql db, you can do all of this in your query.

Comment: Just say var date = new Date(<?php echo date; >);. My syntax might be slightly off right now but from this you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: It is much easier to get the date when the javascript is executed and then input the recorded time into the db. That way no potential for unknown error.

Comment: yes i got it but actually i cant execute the script without visit the website. i mean, if the script starts now, it has to generate a row every 10 mins server sidely, not only when a visitor come in the website. Otherwise a row should be created only IF a visitor come in the website executing the count, and IF are past more of 10 mins. I need only the second conditions.